Find Cov$(Z_n^i,Z_n^j)$ where $Z_n^i=\min\{N_i,p\}$
Suppose that $n$ particles (a fixed quantity) are randomly distributed in the interval $[0,1]$ and the particles are independently coming from the uniform distribution in $[0,1]$. Now, consider any two non-intersecting subintervals of $[0,1]$ and consider $N_i$, $N_j$ to be the number of particles in those subintervals and $p_i,p_j$ be the probability of having a particle in those sub-intervals respectively.
Now, let us consider the random variables $\mathcal Z_n^i=\min\{N_i,p\}$ and $\mathcal Z_n^j=\min\{N_j,p\}$, where $p$ is a constant such that $p\ll n$.
Now, I am trying to find Cov$(\mathcal Z_n^j,\mathcal Z_n^j)$.
We have $$ \mathbb P(N_k=s) = \binom{n}{s}p_k^s(1-p_k)^{n-s} \hskip 1cm \text{where, } k= i,j. $$ Also, we have
\begin{align*}
    \mathbb P(\mathcal Z_n^k =s) &= \begin{cases}
                                        \mathbb P(N_k=s) &\text{if } s<p\\
                                        \mathbb P(N_k\geq p) &\text{if } s=p\\
                                     \end{cases}
                                  = \begin{cases}
                                      \mathbb P(N_k=s) &\text{if } s<p\\
                                      1- \displaystyle\sum_{s=0}^{p-1} \mathbb P(N_k=s) & \text{if } s=p\\
                                     \end{cases}\\
                                  % \end{cases} 
\end{align*}
Then the expectation is given as $$\mathbb E[\mathcal Z_n^k] = p +\sum_{s=0}^{p}(i-p)\mathbb P(N_k=s) $$ I have defined the joint PMF as $$\mathbb P(N_i=l,N_j=m)=\frac{n}{l!m!(n-i-m)!}p_i^lp_j^m(1-p_i-p_j)^{n-l-m}$$ and got the joint PMF as $$\mathbb P(\mathcal Z_n^i=l,\mathcal Z_n^j=m) = \begin{cases}
\mathbb P(N_i=l,N_j=m) &\text{if } l<p,m<p\\
1-\sum_{m=0}^{p-1}\mathbb P(N_i=p,N_j=m) &\text{if } l=p,m<p\\
1-\sum_{l=0}^{p-1}\sum_{m=0}^{p-1}\mathbb P(N_i=p,N_j=p) &\text{if } l=p,m=p
\end{cases}$$
and got the following expectations:
$$\mathbb E[\mathcal Z_n^i\mathcal Z_n^j]= p^3-\sum_{l=0}^{p-1}\sum_{m=0}^{p-1}(p^2+pl+pm-lm)\mathbb P(N_i=l,N_j=m)$$
My doubt is that  $\mathbb E[\mathcal Z_n^i\mathcal Z_n^j]$ must be  $\leq p^2$, but here in some cases it can be $\geq p^2$.
Where I am going wrong!!!

I disagree with your expression for the joint distribution of $\ \mathcal Z_n^i\ $ and $\ \mathcal Z_n^j\ .$ I get
\begin{align}\mathbb P(\mathcal Z_n^i=l,&\mathcal Z_n^j=m)\\
&=\begin{cases}
\mathbb P(N_i=l,N_j=m) &\text{if } l<p,m<p\\
\sum_\limits{r=p}^{n-m}\mathbb P(N_i=r,N_j=m) &\text{if } l=p,m<p\\
\sum_\limits{s=p}^{n-l}\mathbb P(N_i=l,N_j=s) &\text{if } l<p, m=p\\
\sum_\limits{r=p}^n\sum_\limits{s=p}^{n-l}\mathbb P(N_i=r,N_j=s) &\text{if } l=p,m=p
\end{cases}\\
&=\begin{cases}
\mathbb P(N_i=l,N_j=m) &\text{if } l<p,m<p\\
\mathbb P(N_j=m)-\sum_\limits{r=0}^{p-1}\mathbb P(N_i=r,N_j=m) &\text{if } l=p,m<p\\
\mathbb P(N_i=l)-\sum_\limits{s=0}^{p-1}\mathbb P(N_i=l,N_j=s) &\text{if } l<p, m=p\\
{1-\sum_\limits{r=0}^{p-1}\mathbb P(N_i=r)-\sum_\limits{s=0}^{p-1}\mathbb P(N_j=s)\\
\hspace{1em}+\sum_\limits{r=0}^{p-1}\sum_\limits{s=0}^{p-1}\mathbb P(N_i=r,N_j=s)}
 &{\ \\\text{if } l=p,m=p}
\end{cases}
\end{align}
instead. Using this expression for the joint distribution, I get
\begin{align}
&\small\text{Cov}(\ \mathcal Z_n^i, \mathcal Z_n^j)=\\
&\small\sum_{l=0}^{p-1}\sum_{m=0}^{p-1}(p-l)(p-m)\big(\mathbb P(N_i=l,N_j=m)-\mathbb P(N_i=l)\mathbb P(N_j=m)\big)\ .
\end{align}
Here's a somewhat simpler way of confirming this expression for the covariance. First note that
\begin{align}
\text{Cov}\big(\mathcal Z_n^i, \mathcal Z_n^j\big)&=\text{Cov}\big(p-\mathcal Z_n^i,p-\mathcal Z_n^j\big)\ ,\\
\mathbb E\big(\mathcal p-Z_n^x\big)&=\sum_{r=0}^n(p-r)\mathbb P\big(\mathcal Z_n^x=r\big)\\
&=\sum_{r=0}^{p-1}(p-r)\mathbb P\big(\mathcal Z_n^x=r\big)\\
&=\sum_{r=0}^{p-1}(p-r)\mathbb P\big( N_x=r\big)\  \text{ and}\\
\mathbb E\big((p-\mathcal Z_n^i)(p-\mathcal Z_n^j)\big)&=\sum_{l=0}^n\sum_{m=0}^n(p-l)(p-m)\mathbb P\big(\mathcal Z_n^i=l,\mathcal Z_n^j=m\big)\\
&=\sum_{l=0}^{p-1}\sum_{m=0}^{p-1}(p-l)(p-m)\mathbb P\big(\mathcal Z_n^i=l,\mathcal Z_n^j=m\big)\\
&=\sum_{l=0}^{p-1}\sum_{m=0}^{p-1}(p-l)(p-m)\mathbb P\big( N_i=l, N_j=m\big)\ .
\end{align}
Therefore,
\begin{align}
\mathbb E\big(p-\mathcal Z_n^i\big)\mathbb E\big(p-\mathcal Z_n^j\big)&=\sum_{l=0}^{p-1}\sum_{m=0}^{p-1}(p-l)(p-m)\mathbb P\big(N_i=l)\mathbb P\big( N_j=m\big)\ ,
\end{align}
and now subtracting $\ \mathbb E\big(p-\mathcal Z_n^i\big)\mathbb E\big(p-\mathcal Z_n^j\big)\ $ from  $\ \mathbb E\big((p-\mathcal Z_n^i)(p-\mathcal Z_n^j)\big)\ ,$ using the above expressions, gives the same identity as above for the covariance.
